# Does anyone know what does - Fail with error 'ERR_LIMIT_OUT' mean?

Tags: solidity, transactions, ether

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xca244550d8d582d4e77466bc6ef3b9b9a033697ecc71f86c28745e74da354c9c
[image]

Does anyone know what does - Fail with error 'ERR_LIMIT_OUT' mean?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you copy/paste an etherscan link to the contract that failed? I see it in the picture, but I don't want to manually type it!

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xca244550d8d582d4e77466bc6ef3b9b9a033697ecc71f86c28745e74da354c9c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know why an error like that is triggered, you have to check the Code of the contract. On etherscan, click on the contract address, and then on the Contract tab ([here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3e66b66fd1d0b02fda6c811da9e0547970db2f21#code)).

Then, ctrl+f the error name. Here we see that this error is triggered by `require(totalAmountOut >= minTotalAmountOut, "ERR_LIMIT_OUT");`

A quick read of the code tells me that this error is triggered when the actual amount of token out of the swap was less than the minimum amount that was specified by the user for the transaction to succeed.

This generally happen when there was a price change between the time the user sent the transaction and the time it was mined.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful